# Why would one create an empty file?

Tags: file, unix, file-io, terminal

I saw the command: `touch` while watching a video about the `Terminal`

It was something like:

```
user$ touch testfile
user$ ls
Documents Photos Music testfile
```

So I couldn't answer to myself:

> Why one would want to create an empty file?

If you can, please make a short list of a few applicabilities of it!

Comment: touch command not only create empty file, but also change timestamp on existing file - see more here http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch

Comment: This might be a better question for [another](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site as it's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a practical example of when I just used empty files in Ubuntu a few days ago. I was creating a program in `C` that could symlink files, directories, and entire directories of files. After I finished all my coding, I made a simple shell `.sh` script that created a "mock" directory structure. Including empty files and directories so I could test my program symlinking these "fake" files.

This makes it easy to:

1. Start the test over easily if something isn't working.
2. Play around with files of no importance (don't want to risk losing actual data).

Answer (score 2):

- To represent a collection of information with no instances.
- When the mere presence or absence of the file is all that matters

Answer (score 2):

- To test if the script works by using a simple test "Subject"
- To put Items,Codes and others things in later.
- To use it as a example or represent Information.

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
 touch __init__.py
```

all the time in a directory I am importing custom python modules, data files (csv, txt, etc), etc. from.

---

**Explanation:**

In Python, when one wants to import a module in another folder, the target folder needs an `__init__.py` file (that can be completely empty). 
i.e.

```
 from lib import somefile
```

And in the directory lib there is a blank file named `__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

It can be used for lock files, or when the data you need are in the file name itself.  For example, I used to touch a file called "/.MYCOMPUTER_ROOT_2015_AUG_3" (for example) so that when I backed up the root partition on "mycomputer" to tape, I could tell which tape I was reading.

Answer (score 1):

For the paranoid system administrator.

To write a shell script, that executes commands with elevated privileges (as `root` user for example), on a system with multiple concurrent users, and you want to protect your shell script from accidental (or malicious) usage before you're completely done with it. Then you do:

- `touch script.sh` -> creates an empty file that does nothing and cannot be executed because it doesn't have `+x` set, so nobody can do anything harmful.
- `chown` and `chmod` the file, to make sure that only the right users can do anything with it.
- and only then you start `vi` or `emacs` or `nano` or whatever to write your very powerful shell script.

If you do the `chown`/`chmod` *after* you have written the file, then someone else could have already done bad things with it.

EDIT: a better example would be a file with SUPER SECRET CREDENTIALS, for example your `~/.aws/credentials` file with your `aws_secret_access_key`.
If you write the credentials in the file first, and then `chmod` them, then in those few seconds between, someone could steal your file.
If you `chmod` first before there is any content, then you are safe(r).